# Находившемся или находившимся?

Tags: орфография

который в находивш-(е\и)-мся здесь же имении...

Answer (score 1):

В каком? - ***В находившемся***.

А вообще по такому обрывку фраза выглядит довольно странной. 
Трудно себе представить "имение, находившееся тут же".

Answer (score 1):

Да, в находившЕмся. Для подсказки можно использовать любое прилагательное без шипящей и ставить его в тот же падеж. Например, "зелёный". В каком? В зелёнОм (ОМ или ЕМ)